# Unable to update partial cshtml with ajax posted value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

Simply, I have two elements in a partial CSHTML rendered using `@RenderPage` within a larger CSHTML.  One is a dropdown, one is an href. (See the partial CSHTML below.)

When the user picks a different name from the dropdown, the jquery `.change()` method is fired, which posts (`.ajax()`) a numeric value to the page, as such:

```
@{
    var ajax = Request["picked"];
}

<div id="pt_picker">
    @Html.DropDownList("PTPICKER", ...)
</div>

<div id="switcherlink">
    @{
        @Html.ActionLink("Go", "StartFlow", "Person", new { pid = @ajax, redirectUrl = "InSession" }, null)
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#PTPICKER').change(function () {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: window.location.pathname,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { picked: $("#PTPICKER").val() },
                    success: function (result) { alert("ok"); },
                    error: function (result) { alert("not ok"); }
                }
            );
        });

    });
</script>
```

Using the debugger, the numeric value is posted, I can evaluate it, and the debugger appears to hit the Html.ActionLink line again with the new value.  But the resultant page still shows the href with the old value of 'pid'.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the resultant page still shows the href with the old value of 'pid'.

Well, that's because all you did in your success function is an alert. You never replaced the original value with the one coming from your server. From your question it is unclear what partial does the controller action returns but you should use the `result` variable to substitute the corresponding portion in the DOM:

```
success: function (result) { 
    // You need to inject the result coming from your controller action 
    // (and having the updated values) back into the DOM
    $('#some_id').html(result);
},
```

Comment: result contains the entire (new) page HTML.  I want to replace only a small part of it, the div#switcherlink. The code you supplied replaces that div with the entire page.  I'm sure I'm missing something?

Comment: Thanks Darin.  I did this, which seems to get me what I needed.  Thank you very much for the pointer, and please advise if you know of a better way:
    success: function (result) {
        $("#switcherlink").html($("#switcherlink", $(result)).html());
    },